# Why is the algebra map induced on the universal enveloping algebra of a Lie algebra by transposition trivial on the center?

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a classical Lie algebra and $\phi:\mathfrak{g} \rightarrow \mathfrak{g}$, $X \mapsto X^t$, the transpose. $\phi$ induces to an algebra anti-isomorphism $\overline{\phi}: \mathfrak{U}\mathfrak{g} \rightarrow \mathfrak{U}\mathfrak{g}$. Why does the induced map $\overline{\phi}$ restrict to the identity on the center of $\mathfrak{U}\mathfrak{g}$?

I have tried using the Harish-Chandra homomorphism $\theta:Z(\mathfrak{U}\mathfrak{g}) \rightarrow \mathfrak{U}\mathfrak{h}$ (here, $\mathfrak{h}$ is the cartan subalgebra of $\mathfrak{g}$) as well as considering triangular decomposition of $\mathfrak{U}\mathfrak{g}$, but haven't been able to find a proof.

Comment: I feel like this question keeps popping up ... What is the transpose operation on a Lie algebra that is not $\mathfrak{gl}_n$ or $\mathfrak{sl}_n$?

Comment: Maybe "transpose" would intrinsically be "(negative of?) Cartan involution"?